# How create Primary Key is character?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create primary key like this...

```
http://www.example.com/download?d=NAPHMPWI
```

...i.e. the `?d=NAPHMPWI`.

How can I do that?

Comment: No idea what you uploaded, but please keep questions here. Won't download.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the link you have clicked is not available." - You shouldn't expect people to have to click external links to answer your questions anyway.

Comment: He didn't upload anything, he wants to know how to identify rows by a string of letters like MegaUpload does in its URLs. Calm down guys and don't jump to conclusions. Now I have to flag for someone to reopen this as it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: This link only example link ... I want create id like megaupload .

Comment: @Dan Grossman I thought the same thing pretty quickly too. I edited it so hopefully is is clearer, and think I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the primary key an auto-incrementing integer, as most databases support out of the box. Display it as a string for your URLs by converting it to base 36 (which uses digits 0-9 and A-Z).

```
echo base_convert($id, 10, 36);
```

And convert URLs to database identifiers by converting from base 36 to base 10:

```
$id = base_convert($url_key, 36, 10);
```

Comment: What advantages does this have over just using the numeric id?

Comment: That is a correct way to go, however, it has the downside that it is possible to guess other correct IDs (which is something sites like megaupload don’t like you to). Therefore, you should add a bit of redundancy to the identifier, either using cryptography (e.g. use a HMAC), or just append a random string to every ID and store it in the database (and check on retrieval).

Comment: @alex The advantage of answering @meotimdihia's question, and of storing more data with shorter URLs. 10000 takes 5 digits in base 10, 3 digits in base 36.

Comment: Thanks, how can make it always is 8 character ?

Comment: Add 78364164095 to the database identifier when converting to a string, and subtract it when you convert back to get the ID in the database. 78364164096 is the first 8 digit number in base 36 (78364164095 is ZZZZZZZ).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to create a primary key on a `char` column, (like the `d` parameter for the link you posted):

```
CREATE TABLE links (Url CHAR(8) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Url))
```